# Extract sequence values from a long column in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet which contains a column of 150 rows and I need to extract the value of rows 1, 13, 25, 37, 49, 61 & 73 and put the values in a column. I also need to extract the values of rows 2, 14, 26, 38, 50 & 74 and put the values in a separate column.

Here is an example of my input and output column:

[image: spreadsheet with example data]

Say my input column A consists of 10 rows. I want to extract values of rows (n, n+2, n+4, n+6 & n+8) where n=1 to 8. B, C and D are my output columns.

Comment: Any constraints? What have you tried? I mean, you could (assuming your values are in column `A`) just add `=A1`, `=A13`, `=A25` as cell formulas in another column...

Comment: Why not copy, paste special transpose?

Comment: @Lindahl, thanks, i can do that, but its laborious job, coz my column A is big (around 10,000 row), and i have to extract row of (n, n+12, n+25....n+9988),where n=1 to 12.

Comment: can u provide input and output that you are expecting??

Answer (score 0):

Try `index(array, row, [column])`. Reference the column you need to pull from, then list the rows in a separate column in the order you want. For example,

```
    A          B               C                       D
 1 Name      Grade      =index(A2:A4,D2)     Row Referenced in Array
 2 Dan         B             Stacy                     2
 3 Stacy       D              Dan                      1
 4 Jorge       A             Jorge                     3
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it is not happening with the index referencing....i have added an example, please have a look

Comment: @Fahim, i have added an example, please have a look

Comment: @shawpink, looks fine to me. In column B your referencing n+2, so with n = 1 you're pulling index positions 1,3,5,7, and 9. That corresponds to 10,35,40,45, and 55.

Comment: thanks, in this way i have to assign the cells that i want to extract. btw i have written a small code in matlab to do this, now its works.